# How to get DataSource length in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I get the DataSource's length of a ListView?

Suppose I have the following declaration:

```
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged });
...
someObjectsDs = ds.cloneWithRows(someObjectsArray);
```

I've tried `someObjects.length` but this returns me `undefined`.

Comment: I think it's `this.state.datasource._dataBlob` try logging it. It should print out the object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can view the amount of rows to be rendered by calling

```
someObjectsDs.getRowCount()
```

[Official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html#getrowcount)

Comment: This part of documentation is currently very poor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can either dig into the datasource object to find the data and grab the length or you can set the data as a property of the component and refer to that:

```
this.someObjectsArray = someObjectsArray;
someObjectsDs = ds.cloneWithRows(this.someObjectsArray);
```

Now you will be able to do `this.someObjectsArray.length`, just make sure you're updating this variable anytime you're updating the datasource.

Comment: nvm, guess they added a method to get the count now. refer to the answer above.